# Symfony Doctrine datatype only works in findBy not querybuilder

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have custom Datatype, which is working as expected when using FindBy... but doesn't when using query builder. Sorry for the long post, but I figure more info should help.

it's the same as this unanswered question: 
[Doctrine 2 Custom Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813883/doctrine-2-custom-types/25643099#25643099)

## DataType:

```
...
class MyHappyType extends Type
{
    ...
    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
       return 'hippies: '.$value;
    }

    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return 'doubleHippies: '.$value;
    }
    ...
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'hippies';
    }
}
```

## Entity:

```
// Entity class

...
class Hippie
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", unique=true)
     */
     protected $id;

   /*
    * @ORM\Column(type="hippies")
    */
    protected $Sandals;

}
```

## Repository:

```
...
class HippiesRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function useQueryBuilder($sandals){
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('hippie');
        $qb->select('hippie')
           ->where('hippie.Sandals = :sandals')
           ->setParameter('sandals', $sandals);

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

## And finally, Controller:

```
public function hippiesAction()
{
    // this returns an entity with $hippie1->sandals == 'doubleHippies: hippies: red'
    // which is expected behaviour
    $hippie1 = $em->getRepository('HappyHippiesBundle:Hippie')->findOneBySandals('red');

    // this one returns no results, when checking queries run I see that
    // $sandals value isn't translated in to 'hippies: red'
    $hippie2 = $em->getRepository('HappyHippiesBundle:Hippie')->useQueryBuilder('red');
}
```

So in short, Datatypes aren't being converted when using QueryBuilder, only when using FindBy...

Comment: Thinking about this a little more, it seems consistent that Custom types are not taken into account when using Query builder. They are attached to the Entity, it isn't relevant in a query - which is just a query.

So I guess the question is: how do you use methods in custom types in a repository?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the repository class in your entity configuration:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=""AcmeDemoBundle\Entity\HippiesRepository")
 */
class Hippie
{ 
    // ...
}
```

see [Custom Repository classes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes) for more information.

**Update:**

You may also want to get rid of the `->select('hippie')`. When you  use the method to create a `QueryBuilder` in the repository class, the method will automatically call the `select` and `from` methods for you (See the [EntityRepository.php](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/v2.4.7/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php#L81) file for more info). In this case all you need to do is:

```
 $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('hippie');
 $qb->where('hippie.Sandals = :sandals')
    ->setParameter('sandals', $sandals);

 return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```