# Doctrine / Symfony: convert custom type to database value before using QueryBuilder

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have defined a custom Doctrine data type for Uuid. When I search for an object using `find($uuid)`, it works correctly, i.e. the attribute is converted using `convertToDatabaseValue()` before executing the query, and converted back with `convertToPhpValue()` when value is retrieved.

The conversion doesn't work if I use the QueryBuilder. Example:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('s');
$qb = $qb->where( //some conditions...
      $qb->expr()->eq( 's.uuid', ':uuid' ))->setParameter( 'uuid', $uuid );
```

I found two similar unanswered questions:

- [Symfony Doctrine datatype only works in findBy not querybuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664764/symfony-doctrine-datatype-only-works-in-findby-not-querybuilder?answertab=votes#tab-top)
- [Doctrine 2 Custom Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813883/doctrine-2-custom-types/25643099#25643099)

It looks like that the conversion is in fact ignored.

How can I force the conversion of the parameter before executing the query? Is there a way to access the `convertToDatabaseValue()` function of the custom data type from the repository?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution: the function `setParameter()` has a third argument `$type` which is used to declare the typology of the parameter. The custom declared type can be retrieved with the `getType()` function of the Doctrine Type class:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('s');
$qb = $qb->where( //some conditions...
      $qb->expr()->eq( 's.uuid', ':uuid' ))->setParameter( 'uuid', $uuid, Type::getType('uuid') );
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes `setParameter()` has third parameter, but the type of third param as **string** is worked for me not the object.

You can do it in following way.

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('s');
$qb = $qb->where( //some conditions...
      $qb->expr()->eq( 's.uuid', ':uuid' ))->setParameter( 'uuid', $uuid, 'uuid' );
```

If you dont know what exactly key is for datatype 'uuid' is.
Then use `print_r(Type::getTypesMap());` to get list of all dataypes added.

In my case it was

```
Array
(
    [array] => Doctrine\DBAL\Types\ArrayType
    [simple_array] => Doctrine\DBAL\Types\SimpleArrayType
    [json_array] => Doctrine\DBAL\Types\JsonArrayType
    [object] => Doctrine\DBAL\Types\ObjectType
    [boolean] => Doctrine\DBAL\Types\BooleanType
    [integer] => Doctrine\DBAL\Types\IntegerType
    [smallint] => Doctrine\DBAL\Types\SmallIntType
    [bigint] => Doctrine\DBAL\Types\BigIntType
    [string] => Doctrine\DBAL\Types\StringType
    [text] => Doctrine\DBAL\Types\TextType
    [datetime] => Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateTimeType
    [datetimetz] => Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateTimeTzType
    [date] => Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateType
    [time] => Doctrine\DBAL\Types\TimeType
    [decimal] => Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DecimalType
    [float] => Doctrine\DBAL\Types\FloatType
    [binary] => Doctrine\DBAL\Types\BinaryType
    [blob] => Doctrine\DBAL\Types\BlobType
    [guid] => Doctrine\DBAL\Types\GuidType    
    [geometry] => CrEOF\Spatial\DBAL\Types\GeometryType
    [point] => CrEOF\Spatial\DBAL\Types\Geometry\PointType
    [polygon] => CrEOF\Spatial\DBAL\Types\Geometry\PolygonType
    [linestring] => CrEOF\Spatial\DBAL\Types\Geometry\LineStringType
)
```

And my doctrine code was something like this.

```
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');
        $queryBuilder
            ->where('st_contains(:polygon, point(c.latitude, c.longitude) ) = 1')
            ->setParameter('polygon', $city->getPolygon(), 'polygon');
```